# Change color of DataGrid Cell WPF regarding Range

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, controls

Hi I need to implement a function that if the value of the binding items is within the specific range cell color should be according to the range.

I have been using [Changing Background Color Of DataGrid Cell WPF 4](http://asimsajjad.blogspot.com/2010/09/changing-background-color-of-datagrid.html)

this works fine but it is for only if that values are there.what if i want to add range i.e from 10 - 20 it is red 21-30 it is blue

added everything and saw an example at the end but the color does not change here is the code

Class

```
 public class ConvertToBrush : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int tempValue = int.Parse(value.ToString());
            string tempString = "Red";
            if (tempValue >= 0 && tempValue <= 20)
                tempString = "#FF0000";

            if (tempValue > 20 && tempValue <= 40)
                tempString = "#F09300";

            if (tempValue > 40 && tempValue <= 60)
                tempString = "#EDDF00";

            if (tempValue > 60 && tempValue <= 80)
                tempString = "#FFFFFF";

            if (tempValue > 80 && tempValue <= 100)
                tempString = "#85AB00";


            SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
            BrushConverter conv = new BrushConverter();
            brush = conv.ConvertFromString(tempString) as SolidColorBrush;
            return brush;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
```

XMAL

```
  <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CentreAlignStyle}" Binding="{Binding TestResults}" Header="Results" IsReadOnly="True" MaxWidth="60" MinWidth="60" >
                                        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                            <Style>
                                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="{Binding TestResults, Converter={StaticResource makeBrush}}" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Could you re-read my answer? Like the part where i tell you **not to use a datatrigger** but to **bind directly** to the Background?

Comment: can you give example how to bind directly.as i am new i cannot figure the way out

Comment: It really is not that hard, see my edit to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a `DataTrigger` but just bind the `Background` to the value and put in a [`ValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to return the right brush (or no brush at all).

**Edit:** What the usage should look like:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style>
         <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="{Binding TestResults, Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

Comment: can you give a very basic example?

Comment: @Lagrangian: No, read the documentation (which already contains an example), that's why i linked it.

Comment: I wrote the class and now i am having trouble using it.I am new to wpf

Comment: @Lagrangian: Is it in a different namespace? Do you know how to use xmlns? If not [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx). If you have some other trouble, you should tell me **what the trouble is**.

Comment: The cell does not contain a `TextBlock` but there is a `Border` wrapping the content (it also does contain a `TextBox`, so `TextBox.Background` would have worked too).

Comment: It would be the cleanest thing to set the `TargetType` of the style and use the native `Background` property: `<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="..." />
        </Style>`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understood you right, but here goes:

So let's say that "TestResults" contains the value you're talking about. In XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn TextBlock.Background={Binding TestResults, Converter={StaticResource makeBrush}} />
```

Just to make sure we're on the same page here, you define the converter in your XAML like this:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:makeBrush x:Key="makeBrush" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

In the makeBrush converter, you do this:

```
public class makeBrush : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int theValueToConvertToColor = (int)value;
        if (theValueToConvertToColor > 10 && theValueToConvertToColor <= 20)
        {
            return Brushes.Red;
        }
        if (theValueToConvertToColor > 20 && theValueToConvertToColor <= 30)
        {
            return Brushes.Blue;
        }
        //More ifs...
        else return Brushes.Green;            
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The "`object value`" you get in the `Convert` method of your `IValueConverter` is actually the value of "`TestResults`"

Note: I didn't actually test it with a `DataGridTextColumn`, but i guess you get the point and can make the necessary adjustments if required.

Comment: there is strange error it says attachable property  `Background` was not found in type "TextBlock"

Comment: That's what i meant by "adapt"