# Change Text Color of DataGrid Cell when value of bound property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` in WPF, filled with elements of an `ObservableCollection` (`ElementGroup` items that have an ID and a Text property and are read from an XML file). 
What I want to achieve is that the text color of the cell content changes when a user has edited the value of the cell. The color of the cell should remain for example green as soon as the user leaves the cell and the value is different than the original value.

**What I have so far:**

A user control with the following datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Config.ElementGroups, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >            
    <DataGrid.Columns>  
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group Name" Binding="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Nothing in the code behind of the User Control.

The ElementGroup class with the 2 Properties, that also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` (extra class in order to re-use it)

```
public class ElementGroup : NotifyPropertyChangedBase, ITag
{
    private int myId;
    private string myText;

    public ElementGroup()
    {
        Elements = new List<Element>();
    }

    public List<Element> Elements { get; private set; }

    public int Id 
    { 
        get { return myId; }
        set
        {
            if (myId == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            myId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return myText; }
        set
        {
            if (myText == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            myText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The datagrid rows are correctly filled:

[datagrid example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eiZF.png)

I listen to the property changed event in my viewmodel. The event is fired and the breakpoint is hit when I set it to the handler and then change a cell of the datagrid.
The `HasTextChanged` and `HasIdChanged` functions return true if the change is a real change or false if the value was changed to the previous value.

```
private void GroupPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    ElementGroup changedGroup = sender as ElementGroup;

    switch (propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName)
    {
        case "Text":
            GroupChanged = HasTextChanged(changedGroup);
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupChanged");
            break;
        case "Id":
            GroupChanged = HasIdChanged(changedGroup);
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupChanged");
            break;
    }           
}
```

**What I have tried:**

At first I thought I just return a color and bind the foreground color to the datagrid, just as it is working for a simple `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Config.Description}" Foreground="{Binding DescriptionColor}"/>
```

But putting the same Foreground binding to the `DataGridTextColumns` did not work. I tried to adapt the answer found here ([Change Color of DatagridCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986898/change-color-of-datagrid-cell-wpf-regarding-range)) but could not get it to work (`DescriptionColor` in below example is `SolidColorBrush DescriptionColor = Brushes.Green`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Group Name" Binding="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="{Binding DescriptionColor}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

All other cell color change answers I found were about setting a trigger and if the value changes to a specified value, then the color can be changed.

So I decided to go for the "real change yes/no" approach and added a style trigger my datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Config.ElementGroups, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GroupChanged}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GroupChanged}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>  
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group Name" Binding="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This also didn't work and I begin to wonder if I miss something elementary.

Has anybody an idea what I do wrong, or what I have to do to get this to work?
I must admit that I am not 100% understanding how the trigger works and if it really knows what to do...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I clearly understand you want to mark cell what is currently edited by user. So if you are using `DataGridTextBoxColumns` you can add `EditingElementStyle` for them.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="EditingStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

And the columns should look like this.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="Auto"
                    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource EditingStyle}" />
```

**Update**

To remaing color of edited cells you can 1 add some bool props into `ElementGroup` that indicating edited cells. Something like this.

```
private bool _isIdChanged;
public bool IsIdChanged
{
    get { return _isIdChanged; }
    set { _isIdChanged = value; NotifyPropertyChanged( "IsIdChanged" ); }
}
```

2 You should add into the id setter `IsIdChanged = true`.

```
...
myId = value;
OnPropertyChanged();
IsIdChanged = true;
```

3 Change the binding for `ID` column.

```
Binding="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
```

4 Add style for this column.

```
<Style x:Key="IdStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsIdChanged}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataGridTextColumn Name="ID" ... CellStyle="{StaticResource IdStyle}" />
```

5 After binding to the DataGrid should change all values of the `IsIdChanged` of the collection elements to false. And it needed to set it to false after changing values from code behind.

6 Should add same code for other columns. Hope this helps.

**Update**

I've looked at your code, you should change `DataTrigger` binding to this.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IdChanged}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
</DataTrigger>
```

And you should add these strings in the constructor of `ChangeConfigSettingViewModel`. It should be last strings of constructor for initializing `IdChanged` values to false.

```
foreach ( PersonModel pers in myPersons )
{
    pers.IdChanged = false;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but this is not what I want to achieve. Maybe I was not clear enough. I don't want to change the color during editing, but when the value was edited and the user clicks somewhere else, the color should remain.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me too. I see that the property is changed and value is set to "true", but the color won't change... Just as if the information just doesn't come through to the datagrid. Maybe there is something elementary wrong with my code... I think I'll create a new project just to see if it works if I only have this datagrid.

Comment: You can change `DataTrigger` in `Style` to `Binding={Binding Id} Value="5"` and change the id to 5 in `DataGrid` just to test the correctness of adding style to column. In my test example it works fine, maybe there is some problems in `OnPropertyChanged()` function.

Comment: I've tried that, but still. no color change.
I have changed the event handler of the `PropertyChanged` event of the `ElementGroup` items to just show me in a MessageBox the name of the changed property: I get correct info that Id or Text changed when I edit the datagrid cells. But I do not get the message box for the new `IsIdChanged` property.  Unfortunately, binding the id and set a number as value didn't work as well :(   I don't know, but I must be missing something fundamental...

Comment: Can you provide your code with these updates? Maybe I will see something, that we missing.

Comment: Thanks again for your effort. I have created a small and reduced example for which it is not working as well, but unfortunately the company blocks the access to filesharing websites. So I guess I can only do it from home in the evening.

Comment: I have uploaded a small example here (hope it works):  
[Testing.sln](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11208933/tmp_27774-Testing-1873344252.zip.html)  
I really appreciate if you have time to look at it.

Comment: I've checked this and fixed it. And updated the answer how to do. Also I've changed `INotifyPropertyChanged` realization, cause i've old visual studio, if you need this, I can add it.

Comment: Great! Thanks a million!!  
I think when VS underlines the binding property and says "Cannot resolve property", I was just thinking that it will not work. But it works now, so thank you very much.